# Switch pip from /usr/local/bin/pip to /usr/bin/pip

Tags: linux, bash, python

I’m forcefully started pip from `/usr/local/bin/pip` by executing `sudo python3 -m pip install -U pip` command.

Now I want to use pip from `/usr/bin/pip`

to achieve this, I have rename the pip as `/usr/local/bin/pip_backup`

now in I ask, `which pip` or `which pip -a` it shows `/usr/bin/pip` only.

But I can not download or install any package using pip. It says

```
[root@localhost file_name]# pip install snips-nlu
-bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: No such file or directory
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Some relevant info:

```
[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# which python -a
/usr/bin/python
[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# which pip -a
/usr/bin/pip
[root@localhost bot_v4.0]#
```

And this:

```
[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# ll /usr/bin/pip*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   407 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip-2 -> ./pip-2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   407 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip2
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     8 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip-2.7 -> ./pip2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root   407 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip2.7
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     9 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip-3 -> ./pip-3.6
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root     8 May  5  2018 /usr/bin/pip-3.6 -> ./pip3.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 16184 Oct 18 15:38 /usr/bin/pipewire
```

And this:

```
[root@localhost bot_v4.0]# ll /usr/local/bin/pip*
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 223 Apr  4 10:25 /usr/local/bin/pip2
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 223 Apr  4 10:25 /usr/local/bin/pip2.7
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 216 Apr  3 17:05 /usr/local/bin/pip3
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 216 Apr  3 17:05 /usr/local/bin/pip3.6
-rwxr-xr-x. 1 root root 223 Apr  4 10:25 /usr/local/bin/pip_bak
```

Comment: could you add `echo $PATH` and the output to the question? When you start a new shell, does this happen too? If you want a quick bypass, do `ln -s /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip`. But please do not take this as the definitive solution.

Comment: [subhankar@localhost ~]$ echo $PATH
/usr/java/jdk/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk/jre/bin:/usr/java/jdk/bin:/usr/java/jdk/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk/jre/bin:/usr/java/jdk/bin:/usr/java/jdk/lib/amd64:/usr/java/jdk/jre/bin:/usr/java/jdk/bin:/usr/share/Modules/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/var/lib/snapd/snap/bin:/home/subhankar/.local/bin:/home/subhankar/bin

***********************************and******************************************

[root@localhost ~]# ln -s /usr/bin/pip /usr/local/bin/pip
ln: failed to create symbolic link '/usr/local/bin/pip': File exists

Answer (score 0):

Check if the following route exists:

```bash
"$HOME/.local/bin"
```

If so, add the following to `.bashrc` or `.profile`:

```bash
if [ -d "$HOME/.local/bin" ];then
  PATH="$HOME/.local/bin/:$PATH"
fi
```